# Control characters in CSV file and python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

I have an excel file which I saved as csv. When I open and print the csv using python, I get some control characters at the start of the row. The control character is `\x01`. Some rows have one of them in front, other have more than one. Basically in the excel file, the author indented the start of line text in some of the rows.

So far so good. I want to write a small if statement checking if there is a control character and then *do something*

```
import csv
f = open('/Users/Downloads/Book1.csv', 'r')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    if row[1][0] is \x01:
        print("hello")
```

Can someone help me how to compare the control character?

Comment: not opening your file in `rb` mode is going to lead to some bugs.  Probably not *this* one, but binary mode is required for proper EOL handling in the `csv` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put quotes around your escape sequence. And don't use `is` in this case.

```
if column[1][0] == '\x01':
    print('hello')
```

Also, a `csv.reader` emits a sequence of rows, not columns.

Comment: Hi - Thanks a lot for the reply. I am new to python, I forgot 'is' is used to compare object types and == is used to compare values. And yes, it should be row instead of column :) .. learning step by step :)